# Entity Framework Core Migration for ASP.Net Core Class Library

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I've been trying to follow the advice of Ben Cull (http://benjii.me/2016/06/entity-framework-core-migrations-for-class-library-projects), but the database is a little different in that I'm trying to inherit from ASP.NET Core IdentityUser class. I created a new solution containing the default ASP.NET Core Web Application from the VS2015 template (CodeFirstTest). I then added an ASP.NET Core class-library (CodeFirstTest.User) to the solution, which would be the data layer in the application and where I will also be setting up ASP.NET Core Identity.

Following the advice of Ben Cull, I rewrote the CodeFirstTest.User project.json as follows.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  }
}
```

I also created a Program.cs file containing the entry point, and a User class that inherits from ASP.NET Core IdentityUser as shown below.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

namespace CodeFirstTest.User
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) { }
    }

    public class User : IdentityUser
    {

    }

    public class UserIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public UserIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        {

        }
    }

    public class TemporaryDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<UserIdentityDbContext>
    {
        public UserIdentityDbContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
        {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<UserIdentityDbContext>();
            builder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=UserDb;Trusted_Connection=SqlTruncateException;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            return new UserIdentityDbContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the Project Manager Console to create the initial migration, I received the following errors.

```
PM> Add-Migration -Name "Initial" -Project "CodeFirstTest.User"
Could not invoke this command with the startup project 'CodeFirstTest'. Check that 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design' has been added to "dependencies" in the startup project and that the version of 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' in "tools" and 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design' are the same. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798221 for more details.
PM> Add-Migration -Name "Initial" -Project "CodeFirstTest.User"
Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

I corrected the first error, but the second run will cause dotnet to fail with the 'Unhandled Exception' error.
The question...
Am I coding something incorrectly that prevents the migration from executing?

Thank you.

Comment: I've just taken a look and it's looks like you do still need to convert your class library to an app (at least until VS2017 and the tooling is properly released). I currently us ethe CLI tools (dotnet ef migrations) rather than the powershell ones, but either should work essentially the same. Be very careful with your versions, only a certain combination will work correctly.

Comment: Take a look at the versions in Dave's answer below and use his Github project as a reference. Let me know if they do in fact work :)

Comment: I believe that might be the catch.  I believe I remember the CLI tools not working for me unless I did the app workaround, but as he (and I) use the Package Manager console I didn't consider that fact and I preferred not having to.  I was using VS 2015 Community for my example as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** And now this answer appears to be out of date!  Turns out 1.1 has removed this feature.  After upgrade to 1.1 it no longer works.  Odd that this would stop working.  Setting up the class library to work like a console application as Ben Cull suggests appears to be the way to handle it when using EF Core 1.1

---

That blog article is pretty old.  Most things that are from before the .Net Core release while still usually useful, need to be taken with a grain of salt.

You no longer have to fake out a console app in the class library.  I whipped together a sample identity application where the User and DbContext were in a class library.

The class library project.json looked like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview4-final"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview4-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

To show the ClassLibrary namespace and the identity schema coming through in the migration.

[image: Success Example]

A few subtle things to note:

- Passed the options in the DbContext constructor to the base constructor
- WebApplication was the startup project.  The default project in the Package Manager Console was the Class Library.  This is so that it knows where to find Startup.

The whole example solution I put together has been put up on [Github](https://github.com/dvanherten/StackOverflow/tree/master/so-41433129) if you want to use it as a baseline.

Comment: First, my apologies because I was pulled away on another project for 29 days. Second, I was able to complete the initial migration by examining the startup project that was posted. I made two changes to complete the migration. The first change to the code listed in the question was

Comment: The first change to the code listed in the question above was `        public UserIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserIdentityDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }` I also added "CodeFirstTest.User":"1.0.0-*" to the dependencies of the CodeFirstTest project.

Comment: Couple of questions, 1) for true separation of concerns, wouldn't the DbContext initialization also need to move to the class library project? In your code, its still in the web app. 2) I noticed that you don't add any of the identity services in your startup.cs that exists when you create an empty web app with individual user accounts:     services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Comment: There are lots of things you'd normally do that I didn't do in this sample.  It was purely a proof of concept that migrations could exist and be created in a class library.  For the purposes of that context it was not required to wire anything up.

Answer (score 0):

for core 1.1 
after adding the packages with nuget it will not work directly, you will need also to edit the .csproj file like that

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

reference: https://www.benday.com/2017/02/14/walkthrough-entity-framework-core-1-1-with-migrations/