# How do I use DotNet Migrations in .Net Core when my Model and Repository are in a class library?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am following this article/tutorial on how to make a generic repository for ASP.Net Core at:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generic-repository-pattern-in-asp-net-core/

When I download the code I am able to run the migrations and the project runs and works.

But when I follow the directions and try to build from scratch, then when I get to the point where I have to run the migrations:

```
Add-migration MyFirstMigration
```

I get this error:

C:\Tutorials\ASP.Net\Core\GenericRepository\FromScratch\GenericReposotory\GR.Web\project.json(20,43): warning NU1012: Dependency conflict. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.0 expected Microsoft.Extensions.Logging >= 1.1.0 but received 1.0.0 No parameterless constructor was found on 'ApplicationContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to 'ApplicationContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory' in the same assembly as 'ApplicationContext'.

The tutorial had the model and repo defined in a class library including this:

```
namespace GR.Data
{
    public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        new AuthorMap(modelBuilder.Entity<Author>());
        new BookMap(modelBuilder.Entity<Book>());
        }
    }
}
```

The options are passed in from StartUp.cs in the Web Project like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
    }
```

And it gets the connection string from appsettings.json in the Web Project: GR.Web.

In the Package Manager Console I have GR.Data selected as the default project and GR.Web set as the startup project. I get this error:

C:\Tutorials\ASP.Net\Core\GenericRepository\FromScratch\GenericReposotory\GR.Web\project.json(20,43): warning NU1012: Dependency conflict. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.0 expected Microsoft.Extensions.Logging >= 1.1.0 but received 1.0.0 No parameterless constructor was found on 'ApplicationContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to 'ApplicationContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory' in the same assembly as 'ApplicationContext'.

How is the download working and how do I get mine to work.
so confused.
On top of it I had to fool around with it forever to get all the depenanceies on EF Core and Tools Preview on the right versions to get this far.

Is there a better article somewhere on how to do this?

---

I fixed:
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",

to
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",

and now I get this error:

System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Apply' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationalColumnAttributeConvention' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationalConventionSetBuilder.AddConventions(ConventionSet conventionSet)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.SqlServerConventionSetBuilder.AddConventions(ConventionSet conventionSet)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator) 
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel() 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider) 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider) 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProvider provider) 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider) 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProvider provider) 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsAddCommand.Execute(CommonOptions commonOptions, String name, String outputDir, String context, String environment, Action`1 reporter) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsAddCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0()
    at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
 Method 'Apply' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.RelationalColumnAttributeConvention' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not ha ve an implementation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213583/net-core-entity-framework-add-migration-for-context-in-class-library

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433129/entity-framework-core-migration-for-asp-net-core-class-library

Answer (score -1):

In dependancies for the Web Project, GR.Web, I rolled back

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0"
```

to

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1"
```

and now it works.